# Multitenant Facebook like solution

Tags: python, facebook-like, jinja2, multi-tenant

Can I use a solution like the following if I don't know the domain on which my code will run? I sometimes pass the request object to the templates like this, is there a disadvantage in doing so?

template:

`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://{{request.host}}"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>`

handler:

```
class HomeHandler(NewBaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.render_jinja('front.html', request=self.request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good way to handle it.